# C - Function Values not passing properly for one of two integer values

Tags: c, function, variables, pointers

So here is the code - I know something simple is wrong with it but I cannot seem to figure it out. I've tried different number types, pointers, and other ish....the variables `b` and `c` have the correct values within function `separate()` - but when they get passed to `main()` they come out as `b = 0` and `c = -471211` (or something similar)....

What am i missing?  Here's the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    void separate(int a, int b, int c){
      b = a/12;
      c = a%12;   }


   int main(){
     int a = 100
     int b, c;
     separate(a, b, c);
     printf("%i = 12 * %i + %i \n", a, b, c);
```

Comment: C passes values by *value*, not by *reference*; the function works on *copies* of the parameters...

Comment: sorry - i forgot to mention in some "versions" of this basic program type, I could get the c variable to pass the proper value back to main()

Comment: That must have been coincidence.

Comment: @user2141693: with a `return` statement, yeah. But it's tricky to return two values.

Answer (score 5):

In C, all function arguments are passed by value. As such, modifying the arguments doesn't have any effect outside of the function. If you want to modify the arguments of a function, you must pass pointers to it:

```
void change_arg(int *arg)
{
    *arg = 42;
}

int arg = 1337;
printf("Before: %d\n", arg);
change_arg(&arg);
printf("Afer: %d\n", arg);
```

Answer (score 3):

`b` and `c` are not initialized. They are not set in the function since you call by copy.
either return the value you want or use `int*` for your arguments.

I think you need to read up a bit more about how C works.

Comment: Yes I know I need to study - I'm a student learning this in class :-P
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In the function above, you are passing the variables by value, thus the values of `b` and `c` are not changed after the call to `separate()`.  They are uninitialized, so they are random values.

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void separate(int a, int* b, int* c){
    *b = a/12;
    *c = a%12;
}

int main(){
    int a = 100;
    int b, c;
    separate(a, &b, &c);
    printf("%i = 12 * %i + %i \n", a, b, c);
}
```

This passes the address of `b` and the address of `c` to pointers for the function.  The function then modifies the values at the addresses.

Comment: @Blumer  Thanks for cleaning my post up.  New to the forum, etc.

Comment: i'm good to go - thanks a lot....I had a pretty good idea about how pointers and referencing values worked, just needed a little help putting it all together...

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the function as follows

```
void separate(int a, int* pb, int* pc){
  *b = a/12;
  *c = a%12;   }
```

where the parameters `b` and `c` are pointers to int.

Then in the main write something like

```
 int a = 100
 int b, c;            
 int *pb, *pc;

 pb=&b;
 pc=&c;
```

where the variables `pb` and `pc` are pointers to int.
With the intructions `pb=&b;` and `pc=&c;` you assign to `pb` the memory location of `b` and to `pc` the memory location of `c`.

Now if you call

```
 separate(a, pb, pc);
 printf("%i = 12 * %i + %i \n", a, b, c);
```

you get the right output.

Comment: wow you guys are awesome - I've been coming to this website for a year now - this is the first time I've asked a question

Comment: errr - fall 2012 semester I took python (got a B+) and this semester is C - just so you guys don't think I've been studying C for a year ;-)